# Sharepoint 2013 via REST API: Error 403 Forbidden when trying to create item

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a simple list item with the rest api on Sharepoint 2013.
My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('internal_Listname')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify({
         '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Data.internal_ListnameListItem',
         },
         'K1F1': k1f1Result,
    }),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("done");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

When trying to send the data I get the 403 "Forbidden" error.

```
"error":{
   "code":"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
   "message":{
        "lang":"en-US",
        "value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
    }
}
```

- I have full admin privileges on this site and the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution a few days ago:
I forgot to add the request digest form to the body. It should have the following structure;

```
<form runat="server">
   <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
</form>
```

Comment: Vadim Gremyachev's answer worked like a charm. All this did for me was make the page display the error: "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred"

Comment: @DevBot I don't like his answer because the `/contextinfo` request is done before every other one, which is performance poison.

Answer (score 23):

Most likely this error occurs since form digest has been *expired* on the page.

In that case you could acquire a new form digest value by making a `POST` request to `/_api/contextinfo` endpoint.

**Example**

```
function getFormDigest(webUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}


function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties) {
    return getFormDigest(webUrl).then(function (data) {

        return $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Usage

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.WorkflowTasksItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval'
};

createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, 'Workflow Tasks', taskProperties)
.done(function (data) {
    console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: I had to change one thing to get this to work:
return getFormDigest(webUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(function (data) {

Comment: The error persisted even after above code. Eventually identified that it was to do with permissions. The user through which i was trying to add item was having read permissions. After setting permissions to contribute it worked. In summary - a very misleading error message. resulting into waste of time :(

Comment: if i am having a html form with people picker controls , date variabls, single line of text, choice fields etc. how to insert an list item using the REST API

Comment: I am using the below call to create a folder on SharePoint2019 :

POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/Shared Documents/Folder"
}

But I am getting the following error:

403 Forbidden: The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same problem:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> <!-- this make SP 2013 take it legit -->
<div class="style1"> <!-- dont know what, but SP need it -->
 ---your page usually a divs---
</div>
</form>
```