# How to post a json string in to SharePoint rest api in Swift

Tags: json, swift, rest, post, sharepoint

I need your help for resolving two questions.

First One is,

I need to post a json string in to a SharePoint rest api(for e.g.: https://domain/getbytitle('MyList')/items). But When I tried to run my code, I got an error that "**the security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again"**.

After googling I got an answer that I have to add the X-RequestDigest as a header in the request call.

But I could not find an answer on how can I get the value of RequestDigest from server each time whenever I'm posting data to SharePoint rest api.

Second question is,

I need to add the html tag  in my json string as a value while posting data to SharePoint rest api.

When I directly add the  tag as a string, I'm getting an error that An Object node expected.

How can I do this?

Kindly help me to resolve these two issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you've tried and people can give you specific feedback on it rather than guessing.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435432/sharepoint-2013-via-rest-api-error-403-forbidden-when-trying-to-create-item

Comment: Thank you Jaquez and Vini for you reply.

Comment: I was able to get the FormDigestValue from rest api by getting the contextInfo

Comment: Now I would need help for the second question only.
My html tag looks like this.
let htmlToSend = "<a href='https://sptest.petrorabigh.com/sites/LTI/IS/TVS/SitePages/TVSReviewPRViolation.aspx?ViolationID='\"\(self.violationItemID!)\"'>\(self.formatedViolationID)</a>"

and my json looks like this:
let jsonData = ["ID" : htmlToSend]

Comment: When I tried the above code, I got an error "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected"